# Use of Google Fit API in medical device

Tags: device, google-fit, medical

I would like to use the Google Fit API for a medical app in France. The Google Fit data would only be used for the fitness part of the app and would be displayed in graphs for reading purposes.

I saw this in the Terms and Conditions of Google Fit API :

*Google does not intend Google Fit to be a medical device. You may not use Google Fit in connection with any product or service that may qualify as a medical device pursuant to Section 201(h) of the Federal Food Drug & Cosmetic (FD&C) Act.*

As the app will only be available in the European Union, do the same conditions apply to it ?

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this kind of questions but I couldn't find any email address for Google API support.

Thank you